# How can I count commands in a log file?

Tags: windows-xp, statistics, logging

I have hundreds of log files in a single directory, and I want an automated way to browse through the log files to count the number of times each command is used.

- Log files are text files
- There are 100+ different commands
- they all start as "Command: " and then the name of the command.
- It's one line per command
- other lines should be ignored

So I'd like to know if there's a script or software that would do that and sort the results by most used commands, and display the frequency of each command. Something like statistics.

(edit: I'm on Win XP and I have no problems installing programs for this purpose)

Comment: @Johannes Win XP, I never used PowerShell. edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Windows PowerShell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929) you could do something along the lines of:

```
Get-Content *.log |
    Where-Object { $_.StartsWith('Command:') } |
    Group-Object {
        $null = $_ -match '^Command: (\w+)';
        $Matches[1]
    } |
    Select-Object Name,Count
```

For my test file this yields an output like

```
Name Count
---- -----
foo      2
bar      2
baz      1
```

Above code simply reads the log files line by line, pushing each line through the pipeline, it then filters the lines to only use those that start with “Command:”, indicating a command to follow. Then those lines are grouped into the individual commands. This is done by the regular expression

```
 ^Command: (\w+)
```

which matches the string “Command:” at the start of the line, followed by one or more word characters. This assumes the command name follows the colon and space immediately; adjust the regex accordingly if this is not the case. The command name is captured in a capture group which is used for grouping. After that only the name and frequency of the commands are selected.

The `$null =` part for the match is to suppress the output of the `-match` operator which would return always `True` here. We don't want to group by `True bar` but only by `bar`.

**ETA:** Depending on how exactly your input looks, you might want to tweak things a bit.

- Allow empty commands:

  ```
   ^Command: (\w*)
  ```
- Allow arbitrary non-space characters in command names (and empty commands):

  ```
   ^Command: ([^ ]*)
  ```

Comment: This works great, but when the "Command: " is empty or starts with an asterisk, it gives an error. Other than that it's perfect. any ideas on that?

Comment: @ume: Well, without details on how exactly your lines look this was a bit of guessing. To allow empty commands, replace the `+` in the regular expression by an asterisk `*`. To allow for more characters you can replace the `\w` by a dot `.` but that might match too much ... if spaces terminate your command names, then you can use `[^ ]` (note the space within the brackets) as a replacement for `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

What OS?

This isn't a perfect match to your requirement, but...

```
grep -i -c Command *.log
```

will get you the number of occurrences broken down by file.  You could then parse that output to get your totals.  Dump it to a text file and pull it into Excel or something.  Not hugely difficult, but admittedly not completely automated either.  I often find that I spend more time searching for a completely automated solution than I do using something like this...  You can get grep for Windows using [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.com/).